# PowerShell replace line with another line in text file doesn't work as expected when attemtping to run Powershell commands from Batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace, config, openvpn

As I mentioned in title, I have created a Batch script which fires some Powershell commands for replacing a line in the `.ovpn` config file which is basically text file, with desired line, but it doesn't work as expected.

This is the current content of the .ovpn file, I am trying to modify:

```
.....
.....
auth-user-pass "C:\\path\\to\\.old-auth"
....
....
```

And desired content of the file is this:

```
.....
.....
auth-user-pass "C:\\path\\up\\to\\.new-auth"
....
....
```

And for that I have writtent this script which is supposed to change the exact line without any issues, but clearly that's not happening. And after making sure that every variable and string manipulation in Batch script is working, I have no clue what's going wrong on Powershell's end:

```
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "VpnCfgDir=C:\path\up\to\"
set "DestFile=!VpnCfgDir!\.new-auth"
set "VpnAuth=!DestFile!" && set "VpnAuth=!VpnAuth:\=\\!"

PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -NoExit -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Maximized -Command "$line = Get-Content \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\" | Select-String 'auth-user-pass' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line; $content = Get-Content \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\"; $content = $content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line, 'auth-user-pass \"%VpnAuth%\"'} | Set-Content \"!VpnCfgDir!\\<vpn_name>.ovpn\""
```

Can anyone help fixing and achieving the intended functionality ?

Comment: The `-replace` operator and `Select-String` both work off RegEx, so you may need to escape your searches like `$_ -replace [regex]::escape($line), 'auth-user-pass \"%VpnAuth%\"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could work. Without knowing the exact error or issue you're running into, It's hard to say but I think a simple parse of the text file using a split could work.

```
$contentPath  = \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\"; Set-Content -Path $contentPath -Value ((Get-Content $contentPath | Select-String \"auth-user-pass\").ToString().Split(\".\")[0] + \".NewAuthHere\")
```

Easier to read format:

```
$contentPath  = \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\"
Set-Content -Path $contentPath -Value ((Get-Content $contentPath | 
Select-String \"auth-user-pass\").ToString().Split(\".\")[0] + \".NewAuthHere\")
```

We could also make your `.new-auth` file name dynamic using a variable

```
$newAuthFile = \".new-auth\";$contentPath  = \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\";Set-Content $contentPath -Value ((Get-Content $contentPath | Select-String \"auth-user-pass\").ToString().Split(\".\")[0] + $newAuthFile)
```

Easier to read format:

```
$newAuthFile = \".new-auth\"
$contentPath  = \"!VpnCfgDir!\<vpn_name>.ovpn\"
Set-Content $contentPath -Value ((Get-Content $contentPath | Select-String \"auth-user-pass\").ToString().Split(\".\")[0] + $newAuthFile)
```